# Condition for fourth degree polynomial to have all real roots

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For what range of values of $a$ will the following fourth degree polynomial have all real roots:

$$x^4 - 2ax^2 + x + a^2 -a = 0$$

Comment: Is $a\in \Bbb R$?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's particularly helpful, but the polynomial is the same as $$(x^2-a)^2+(x-a)=0.$$

Comment: @Clayton I was about to key in the same thing. From this, we can say that the root has to be less than $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First transform this equation into the equation with unknown $a$:

$a^{2}-(2x^{2} + 1)a + x^{4} + x = 0$

Solving the equation with unknown obtain two second degree equations:

$x^{2} + x - a = 0 $ and $ x^{2} - x + 1 - a = 0$

For $a < - \frac{1}{4}$ equation has no real roots

For $a = - \frac{1}{4}$ equation has two equal real roots

For $- \frac{1}{4} < a < \frac{3}{4}$ equation has two different real roots

For $a=\frac{3}{4}$ equation has real four roots of which three are equal

For $ a> \frac{3}{4}$ equation has four different real roots

Comment: Brilliant! I tried a lot to factorize it, but I never realized that it was a quadratic in a! :)

Answer (score 7):

Let denote $f(x)=x^4 - 2ax^2 + x + a^2 -a = 0$. We have
$$f'(x)=4x^3-4ax+1\quad;\quad f''(x)=12x^2-4a$$

If $f''\geq0$ then $f'$ is increasing and then $f$ has at most two real roots so a necessary condition to have 4 real roots is 
$$f'' \quad\text{change sign}\iff a>0$$
and the roots of $f''$ are $\alpha=-\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}$ and $-\alpha$ and if we see the variations of $f'$ we find
$$f \quad \text{has 4 real roots}\iff a>0,\quad f'(\alpha)>0,\quad f'(-\alpha)<0$$

**Edit**
We have 
$$f'(\alpha)=8\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^{3/2}+1>0\quad \forall a>0$$
and we can find easily (*except miscalculation*) that
$$f'(-\alpha)<0\iff a>\frac{3}{4}$$
so we conclude
$$f \quad \text{has 4 real roots}\iff a>\frac{3}{4} $$

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I edited my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks for this. :)

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane But there is still one more condition right, since you have proved that f'(x) has three real roots (let them be l,m,n such that l>m>n, now we also have to take the condition f(l) < 0; f(m) >0 ; f(n) < 0